# Parse a XML file in a specified format iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xml, ipad

*Is there anyway through through which I can parse this XML file that is in this following format:-*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CountryList>
  <Country CountryId="AF">Afghanistan</Country>
  <Country CountryId="AX">Akrotiri</Country>
  <Country CountryId="AL">Albania</Country>
...........................................
...........................................
```

**I need the Country ID and the name:- i.e "AL" and "Albania"** , *So, is  it possible to parse specified XML, and store Country Id and country name in an Array.
Any suggestion will be helpful.*

Comment: @Wain , I have not tried anything , as per I can see, this XML is not in correct format through which I can parse the  Country ID and the Country name and there is no specific tag for Country ID.That is why I am asking is there any other alternative way to parse it.

Comment: The CountryId is actually a XML attribute, have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787078/how-to-parse-xml-attributes-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NSDictionary(value for key) for saving the values. You can use this library for getting and saving the values:

[Parse XML](https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary)
You can find all instructions to extract the required data on mentioned page.

Comment: Thanks but even I know I have to use NSDictionary valueForKey to get a value, but I don't find any answer in your post.

Comment: Answer? Are you looking for code to parse the XML ?

Comment: Your link helped me. But you must include some sample code how to do it only posting link in answer is not a good way. Hope u take my statement on a good note.

Comment: I already marked it as answer, before you have provided any sample code.

Comment: Bro! sometimes we can't write code and check it, we just can provide the info to help the person who is looking for the solution. Happy to know that it helped you! Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

*With the help of Omer Waqas Khan link, just posting the code , you can obviously find the XMLDictionary class from the following link  [nicklockwood/XMLDictionary](https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary)*

---

```
#import "XMLDictionary.h"

 NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"EDUCountry" ofType:@"xml"];
 NSDictionary *xmlDoc = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLFile:filePath];
 NSLog(@"xmlDOC=%@",xmlDoc);
 NSArray *arr=[xmlDoc valueForKey:@"Country"];
 NSLog(@"Country Name and code=%@",[arr objectAtIndex:4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can parse this xml using `NSXmlParser`

using below methods:

1. `didStartElement`
2. `foundCharacters`

you can get `CountryId` in `attributeDict`

```
Swift code:
```

in `didStartElement` method:

```
currentElement = elementName // currentElement is global variable which store the current element name 
if elementName == "Country"
{
let id = attributeDict["CountryId"] as? NSString // attributeDict is parameter variable in didStartElement method
// here you can store id in array
}
```

> If any tag containt value then it will call `foundCharacters` method

write below code in foundCharacters method Like This :

```
if currentElement == "Country"
{
// store country name from here to array there is paramenter name `string` in `foundCharacters` method
}
```